# Does Hawkmoth choose the powers of his minions?

Tags: miraculous-ladybug

When Hawkmoth akumatizes his victims, they take on powers and characteristics, usually related in some way to their non-akumatized identities.

Does Hawkmoth have any influence over what persona and powers his minion villains receive, and simply likes choosing apt personas, or does it happen according to some process?

> In particular, when he became the Collector, was that a deliberate choice, or simply the natural combination of his personality and anger with the akuma?

Sometimes he seems to tell the akumatized villains what powers they will have (for example, he tells Reverser what he'll be able to do); but perhaps he only knows this *after* they've been corrupted, since he never seems to mention this beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Maybe, at least in part

In "Heroes' Day: Catalyst", Hawkmoth seems to have a plan by which he akumatizes Lila Rossi into Volpina, and has her create an illusion to demoralize the people of Paris.

He then akumatizes Nathalie Sancoeur into Catalyst, with her cooperation. She gives him some sort of boost, allowing him to create multiple akuma, which seem to target his previous victims and re-akumatize them into versions of their old forms.

- On the one hand, the fact that all the Catalyst-akumatized villains took on the exact same forms that they had previously suggests that Hawkmoth did *not* control what form they took. Otherwise he would have chosen powers that the heroes had not dealt with before, or at least they wouldn't have had any default form.
- Similarly, the fact that he specifically had to get Lila angry enough to turn *her* into Volpina to create the illusion strongly suggests that he couldn't just choose to give her power to Nathalie, since that would have been the easier and more obvious choice.
- On the other hand, the fact that his whole plan hinged on turning Nathalie into Catalyst suggests that he was able to *choose* to give her the Catalyst powers.

One possible explanation is that Hawkmoth did *not* control Natalie's power. Rather, he already knew that Nathalie would have that power set, because he'd akumatized her before, possibly as practice. It's also possible that there's a *finite* list of powers, and that Hawkmoth and Nathalie knew what power she'd get based on her character.

Further evidence is provided by Season 3, Episode 1, in which he akumatizes Lila. He says "I have some new powers for you, Chameleon" again implying that he can choose which powers to give. In addition, she doesn't get akumatized into Volpina this time. On the *other* hand, she *still* gets somewhat illusion-based powers (although she seemingly can also copy powers), in a similar vein to Volpina, and Hawkmoth doesn't choose to give her a stronger power set such as that of Catalyst or Style Queen, perhaps again suggesting that he doesn't have total control over which powers he grants.